# Why we lose the View caching feature on ViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, synthetic

Kotlin Android Extensions allow us to access views in the layout XML just as if they were properties, with the name of the id you used in the layout definition. It builds a local view cache for this purpose.

But with the `RecycleView` adapter we loose this possibility.

I know that with Kotlin Android Extensions 1.1.4 the solution is solved with `LayoutContainer` interface. But question is not about this.

My question is why it is not possible for Kotlin Android Extensions plugin to create view cache with `ViewHolder` view? What is the reason? I can provide proper synthetic import, for example:

```
kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_item.view.*
```

Why it's not possible to generate view cache with this imported view?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I hurried with the question. I found answer by myself, but maybe someone will come in handy.
Answer is in Kotlin Bytecode.

This is `_$_findCachedViewById` generated with Kotlin Android Extensions plugin for Activities:

```
public View _$_findCachedViewById(int var1) {
  if (this._$_findViewCache == null) {
     this._$_findViewCache = new HashMap();
  }

  View var2 = (View)this._$_findViewCache.get(var1);
  if (var2 == null) {
     var2 = this.findViewById(var1); // this is an Activity reference
     this._$_findViewCache.put(var1, var2);
  }

  return var2;
```

}

This is `_$_findCachedViewById` generated for `ViewHolder` that implement `LayoutContainer` interface:

```
public View _$_findCachedViewById(int var1) {
  if (this._$_findViewCache == null) {
    this._$_findViewCache = new HashMap();
  }

  View var2 = (View)this._$_findViewCache.get(var1);
    if (var2 == null) {
      View var10000 = this.getContainerView();
      if (var10000 == null) {
        return null;
      }

      var2 = var10000.findViewById(var1); // var2 is a сontainerView reference
      this._$_findViewCache.put(var1, var2);
    }

    return var2;
}
```

If the extensions plugin create cache for `Activity` or `Fragment` it use their references for finding views by id. With `ViewHolder` that implement `LayoutContainer` interface it use `containerView` reference for finding views. BUT with `ViewHolder` without `LayoutContainer` the Kotlin Extension Plugin does not now which reference to use for finding views.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [extension keep](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/android-extensions-entity-caching.md#view-holder-pattern)?

Without explicit `LayoutContainer` interface you can find view within a given view - but extension itself has no idea where to store the cache.